# isntalling marketplace extension on magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, module, marketplace

i want to install marketplace extension on magento 2.2 but don't know how.
i've opend my ssh but what to do now?
or do i have to upload this extension's files directly on cPanel? If yes, then please tell me the path where the file of extension should be uploaded.
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you got solution ?

Comment: no @Pawan im still working to find the soltuion

Comment: Hello @Laiba, did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

To install your extension by ssh and magento cli, upload your module files on `app/code` folder. Pay attention on the extension files, there is a structure that it must respect, see how it must appear:

> app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/ all other module files ...

so you can run this comands (be with prompt on your magento folder installation):

`php bin/magento module:status` to list all your modules, installed or not.

`php bin/magento module:enable YourVendor_YourModule` to enable your module, where "YourVendor" and "YourModule" must be overrided by vendor name and module name.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade` setup your module configurations on magento.

And depending of what your module do, and where it acts, the following commands must be necessary, maybe.

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: @ipFranz 
i've uploaded the file in the backend app/code/my_module ... i am using medma marketplace ... now do i have to run command as : 
>php bin/magento module:enable medma_marketplace ?

Comment: Normaly, the name of a module is in camel case, like: Medma_Marketplace, but to be sure about it, open the **registration.php** file of your module, the name is the only string at that file.

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package Medma_MarketPlace at any version for your minimum-st
  ability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

this is the error im facing

Comment: Aparently, your folders structure are with some error, if the name of your module is "Medma_MarketPlace", you must have a structure like this: *app/code/Medma/MarketPlace/*, and then in this folder are all the module files, like registration.php, etc folder, Block folder, etc.

Comment: About your other issue, *could not open the file bin/magento* error, I suggest to you create another question, cause post an answer as another question violates some forum rules, and it can be a problem.

Comment: yes i've updated and placed the extension under app/code/medma/marketplace/

Comment: See the capitalized letters, I think it is **M**edma/ **M**arket**P**lace, it should follow the name setted in your **registration.php**, thats why I wanted to see these files.

Comment: So, it works? I am curious about this extension, here we was thinking to buy it, can u give me some informations?

Answer (score 0):

after uploading my marketplace-module in

> app/code

i've run the command as

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

but it gave me the following error as shown in image :
[image]

i checked the file permission of magento in

> bin/magento
>   it is set to 0755
>   after that i tried to change the permission to 0777
>   but no chnage im still getting this error

```
could not open the file bin/magento
```

can anoyone tell me what is going wrong from my side?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `could not open the file bin/magento` because you are not running the command from your Magento installation location, instead you are trying to run it from your home directory.